# How to construct a Red-Black tree representing K in O(lg n)

Tags: algorithm, tree, key, logarithm, red-black-tree

Suppose that K1 and K2 are sets of keys, and k is a key such that for any k1 ∈ K1 and k2 ∈ K2 we have k1 < k < k2.
Let K = K1 ⋃ {k} ⋃ K2.
Assuming that K1 and K2 are represented as RB-trees, each node of which additionally
keeps the black height of that node, describe how in O(lg n) time to construct an RB-tree
representing K.
I have been trying to solve this but I couldn't. Anyone can help? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If K1 and K2 have the same black height, then we make k the new (black) root, with left subtree K1 and right subtree K2.

Otherwise, we have to either descend K1's right spine or K2's left spine to find a subtree with the same black height as the other tree. Merge these trees as above except make k red, then if needed, apply the usual recoloring plus rotation algorithm to fix a violation.